# CSS z-indices

Tags: css, xhtml, z-index

I have an element whose position is fixed and has a z-index = 5. When I resize the browser this element appears in front of (statically positioned) elements whose z-index = 10, which is not the behaviour I expect.

If you want to see what I mean, open [this page](http://chaletsdesbouleaux.com/test/) and narrow the browser window until the "Chalets des Bouleaux" logo is over the photo (the former has a z-index = 5 and the latter has z-index = 10).

Thanks,
Don

Comment: I don't know if it's an issue here, but I've had similar trouble when objects weren't siblings in the DOM.  Some browsers will obey z-index regardless, while others (IE?) will only respect it between pairs of elements that have the same parentNode.  Or something like that.  I think.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to add "position: relative" to the elements with z-index 10.

Comment: Make that *definitely*. `z-index` only applies to positioned elements. So that z-index of 10 isn't doing anything: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/z-index

Answer (score 0):

So the Chalets logo should appear over the image?  Looks fine in IE8.